# Basics of i18next

Tags: i18next

Im new to i18n and when I typed it in the search bar [i18next](http://i18next.com/index.html) is in the top results.
I already did my research regarding i18n and how to use it. But it still not clear to me. All I know is that to be able to make your web app available to other language, you need to do a json file that contains the keys and value of your app, and you need to add a script for the i18n.

The rest is still confusing for me. This might sound a stupid question for you, but I just cant understand how it works.

1) Im not sure but based on my observation, you only create a json translation  for those that have a value or text that will be shown in the page. Correct? Assuming in the html file, I have a text that is not inside a label or innerhtml, example:

```
<html>
<body>
**How are we going to translate this text? What key am I going to use?**
</body>
</html>
```

What do I need to do to translate this text?

2) What should we use as the key? id? class? tag? Because I've seen different examples and it uses different any of these. When is the right time to use these?

3) regarding the key-value pair, what if the pair is coming from  the server? what's the syntax for this?

4) When do we need a multi line json?

Answer (score 0):

i18n is a big topic, with a lot of solutions depending on what kind of web app you are trying to internationalize / localize. Unfortunately, i18next's documentation is not very good, and it has next to nothing in way of tutorials.

That said, you might be best off taking a look at the sample app on i18next.js's github repository here: https://github.com/jamuhl/i18next/tree/master/sample/static. It does give some examples of how i18next can be used to replace html text with localized versions of the same. To answer some of your questions:

1. There are a few ways of doing this. The sample script replaces much of the data by using the jQuery *.text* call -- something like this: `$('#MyHTMLID').text($.t('ns.common:MyLocalizedTextForMyHTMLID'));`. Any html inside the id "MyHTMLID" is replaced by the localized data for the key "MyLocalizedTextForMyHTMLID' by the i18next *.t* call.
2. A lot of these decisions are just convention. Keep it simple, be consistent.
3. Normally in a web app the json file *is* on the server, in a locales subdirectory of the directory where your html resides. Take a look at that i18next example for how it's laid out.
4. When you're first building your web app, use a multi-line json file to be able to troubleshoot. You can compress it later using something like http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/.

Hope this helps get you started!